# Why does the ternary operator with the some method make this statement false?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, conditional-operator

Couple of questions here. This is from Wes Bos' 30 Days of JavaScript course.

1. Why does the ternary operator (commented out) make this false?
2. Why is my solution incorrect?

### Challenge

```
const people = [
    { name: 'Wes', year: 1988 },
    { name: 'Kait', year: 1986 },
    { name: 'Irv', year: 1970 },
    { name: 'Lux', year: 2015 }
];

// Array.prototype.some() // is at least one person 19 or older?
// Array.prototype.every() // is everyone 19 or older?
```

### Wes' Solution

```
const isOlderThan19 = people.some(function(person) {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    // (currentYear - person.year >= 19) ? true : false
    if (currentYear - person.year >= 19) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

### My Solution

```
const isOlderThan19 = (element) => {
    let age = new Date().getFullYear() - element.year;
    age >= 19;
}

console.log(people.some(isOlderThan19));
```

I tried logging the ages that are being set to the console. All but one of the people are over 19 but it returns false. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- The ternary operator has no `return` before it, so the function defaults to return `undefined`, which is not desired.

2- `isOlderThan19` is not returning anything, you probably missed the return word before `age >= 19`

Both examples fails due to missing the `return` statement.

Comment: And the same problem in the first version with the ternary operator.

Comment: Damn. I assumed too much from the arrow function. That's embarrassing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const isOlderThan19 = (element) => {
    let age = new Date().getFullYear() - element.year;
    return age >= 19;
}

console.log(people.some(isOlderThan19));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ternary statement needs to actually return, and not just be a boolean

```
(currentYear - person.year >= 19) ? return true : return false
```

or more accurately

```
const isOlderThan19 = people.some(function(person) {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    return (currentYear - person.year >= 19) ? true : false
});
```